# Creating integer literal expression with Roslyn

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, roslyn

How do I create expression for integer literal (say 2) using Roslyn syntax factory?

When I viewed it under debugger, it looks like it has type `NumericLiteralExpression`, but I cannot find how to create it?

Closest, I found was `SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression, SyntaxFactory.Token(..))`, but I don't know how to create a token representing value 2.

Comment: http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually found out after some trial and error. Following seems to work.

```
SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression, SyntaxFactory.Literal(2))
```